# Diagnostic session doesn't works on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a problem with visual studio 2017.
At the end of my program, I always have had a window like this (no matter the mode - debug or release - ).

[image: diagnostic tool]

But now, it appears only in "debug" mode ; in "release" it doesn't appear
anymore. But I need it in order to see the time of 
execution of the code. Yesterday it worked and now it doesn't..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happen that this windows dissapeard. Have you tried turning it on in release configuration by cliking: [image: vs2017]

Other thing to consider it that this is not a proper way to measure execution time of your program. When you attach a debuger even in release mode your program is slowed down. Instead you can use code like this (in c++) in you main function:

```
#include <chrono>

int launch(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  //all of your old main code
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   using std::chrono;
   high_resolution_clock::time_point tic = high_resolution_clock::now();

   launch(argc, argv)  //your whole program runs here

   high_resolution_clock::time_point toc = high_resolution_clock::now();
   std::cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(toc - tic).count() << "\n";
}
```

Then you can start your program by Ctrl+F5 (start wihtout debugging). After execution on console you will have precise amount of miliseconds that your program run for. Also remember to run it several times as OS like windows is not real-time system so depending on load of your machine this time may differ.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I don't understand very well how to measure execution time of my program. I have to put my main where ther's your comment, without braces and without "  int main () " ? I tried different ways to do this but it doesn't works:)

Comment: basically yes, what you can do is create such a function. I will edit answer to make it more clear. No if your program can run from start to end without errors this should work. If there are some errors in your code it may happen that you will never get to this std::cout and you will not see time. But there is little sense in measure how fast your program works when it doesn't work.